# Jquery datepicker can't display the value....?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a textfield called:"deadline", which is have the value,like this:

```
    <input type="input" maxlength=10  value="2011-09-14" id="deadline" name="deadline" class="date_picker"></input>
```

But when I ran this js, it is gone, I can't see the value:

```
    $('.date_picker').datepicker();  
    $('.date_picker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd', 'showOn', '');
```

Why the date_picker disappear my value? If I want it back,how can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: `value="2011-09-14"` and then `'yy-mm-dd'`? Is the year to be 2 digits or four?

Comment: I just follow the example, using 'yy':http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-formats

Comment: Well Y represents Year, M month, and D day. So, if you want to format your date like "2011-09-04", that's "YYYY-MM-DD". You've currently set it to "YY-MM-DD" which is incompatible. Take a look at my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Date Picker will typically clear your HTML given default value depending on your formatting options. It does, however, have an option for setting the Default Date:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

**Important Note: Make sure you Default Value matches the format of your dateFormat**

So, add to your options the dateFormat with either a string of your value or a JavaScript date object. More information:

> Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank.
>   Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the
>   current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a
>   string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for
>   weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

Finally, if you continue to have problems, your options string might be malformed. I haven't seen an options string implemented like that, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work. If you still have issues, try implementing your options in a similar format to this:

```
$( ".date_picker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Comment: if i set the format as you mention, the value is appear, but the calendar output format is strange: 09/05/2011

Comment: When you say the calendar format, what specifically do you mean? When you change the date with the calendar it enters into the textbox "09/05/2011" ? If so then your `dateFormat` isn't set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to get it worked, and found a solution using jquery nothing else was working. 
I did it as

```
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".datepicker").val('2011-09-14');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ShaneC was almost correct. The date format should be `yy-mm-dd`, as one `y` actually represents two digits in year. See the date format list here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate.

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/william/RtYLB/.